# how to retreive data from firestore of a field with multiple values

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, arraylist

This code is written in Java programming language and uses the Firebase Firestore database to retrieve data. The code retrieves dynamic data of multiple users, and each user has multiple tests. The data includes dwell time, flight time 2, and flight time 3, and the name of the test. but lets assume that the field in this case (dwelltime,ft2,ft3) is a table containing multiple values in the firestore how can i retreive all the data in a single table. i would be extremly grateful any help i would appreciate it

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) { 
    mdw.add(document.getLong("dwelltime")); 
    mft2.add(document.getLong("ft2"));
    mft3.add(document.getLong("ft3"));
    name.add(doc.getString("nom"));
    Log.d("getdata1", "y = " + y);
}
```

this is a screenshot of my firebase data :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CuxB.png)

i tried the following but i only get the first document of the users. something is missing

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) { 
    ArrayList<Long> dwellTimes = (ArrayList<Long>) document.get("dwell time");
    dwell.addAll(dwellTimes);

    ArrayList<Long> flightTimes2 = (ArrayList<Long>) document.get("flight time 2");
    flightm2.addAll(flightTimes2);

    ArrayList<Long> flightTimes3 = (ArrayList<Long>) document.get("flight time 3");
    flightm3.addAll(flightTimes3);

    name.add(doc.getString("nom"));

    Log.d("getdata1", "y = " + y);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show a screenshot of the Firebase console with a document containing the data that you're trying to read.

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I retrieve all the data in a single table"? Please show us a concrete example. Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.